# Getting Sonar Critical defect on HTTP Security Configuration authorizeRequests()

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

I have a spring boot application that I am getting the following Sonar Critical defect on my configuration function at the line calling authorizeRequests().  How should I fix it?  Thanks.

```
Make sure that Permissions are controlled safely here. Controlling permissions is security-sensitive. 
 It has led in the past to the following vulnerabilities:

 CVE-2018-12999
 CVE-2018-10285
 CVE-2017-7455
```

My Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http            
        .authorizeRequests()  // Sonar complain this line here
        .antMatchers("/v1/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic()
        .and().cors();
   }
}
```

Comment: can you mention sonar rule name/id

Comment: @Shailesh Chandra  Is this the rule "owasp-a5, sans-top25-porous"  and squid:S4834

Comment: Sonar does tell you solution along with reported issie, i cant access my sonar server as of now to provide further details, only thing i can suggest instead of writing/**, use absolute URL and validate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked up the error description in sonar, and below is the description of error as per sonar.

> Controlling permissions is security-sensitive. It has led in the past
>   to the following vulnerabilities:
>
> - CVE-2018-12999
> - CVE-2018-10285
> - CVE-2017-7455
>
> **Attackers can only damage what they have access to. Thus limiting their access is a good way to prevent them from wreaking havoc, but it has to be done properly.**
>
> This rule flags code that controls the access to resources and
>   actions. The goal is to guide security code reviews.

Below is the code which is causing sonar issue

```
.authorizeRequests()  // Sonar complain this line here
.antMatchers("/v1/").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
```

As I mentioned in comments of your question, don't blindly authorize the requests, access should be restrictive something like below

```
http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/", "/home").access("hasRole('USER')")
  .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
  .and()
  // some more method calls
```

If this is your test/non-production code just add //NOSONAR at line it's complaining issue, sonar will bypass this but **Don't use //NOSONAR in the production environment.

Comment: But how to add  "//NOSONAR", where to add, would you Please show the way of configuring what you suggest?

Comment: @HaykMkhitaryan just add **/NOSONAR** at the end of line which you want to be ignored

Comment: You should make sure to add a catch-all `.anyRequest().denyAll()` at the bottom of the list.